# Spring boot auto-config fails on maven build with Camel 2.19

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm building a Java Camel project using Maven 3.3.9 and Camel 2.19.5, everything compiles, but on validation Maven fails with the error below. Looks like Spring boot is trying to auto-configure something. The project is not a typical Springboot app, it's a custom Maven plugin that happens to depend on Camel. My suspicion is Maven's expecting to find main() in the code but it does not exist since the project has no runnable main(). Anyway, that's what I think, it's a nasty issue I'll tell ya that.

```
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 10.344 s
        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-22T16:13:41-04:00
        [INFO] Final Memory: 39M/622M
        [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
                org.apache.camel:camel-package-maven-plugin:2.19.5:
                  prepare-spring-boot-auto-configuration
                  (validate) on project ofi-salesforce-maven-plugin: 
                Execution validate of goal org.apache.camel:camel-package-maven-plugin:2.19.5:
                  prepare-spring-boot-auto-configuration
                  failed: Cannot find Apache Camel project root directory
```

Comment: ...So why *don't* you have a main method?

Comment: The app is a Maven plugin; it has no main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; the code was previously using Camel 2.15.1, but after upgrading to Camel 2.19.1 we failed to consider Maven build changes. Since our code is branched from Camel Salesforce Maven plugin, the pom for that project now includes [camel-package-maven-plugin](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.19.5/components/camel-salesforce/camel-salesforce-maven-plugin/pom.xml), which we failed to include in our pom. The plugin skips **validation** phase, and that's where the error was happening, makes sense.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>prepare</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>validate</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>readme</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```